# Boot (Ubuntu) from grub manually

Tags: boot, grub2

I made an USB drive where I installed GRUB 2 to first partition and unpacked Ubuntu files from downloaded iso 18.04 to second partition.

grub.cfg menu entry from iso file has two entries: linux and initrd. As per GRUB manual I enter `linux` with path to vmlinuz on (hd0,msdos2), `initrd` with path too (no errors up to this point) and then finally `boot` command in GRUB prompt.

After some messages finally having never ending `stdin in not typewriter` something message on my screen. What am I missing? What should I do to start Ubuntu with desktop manually from GRUB prompt?

Comment: @user535733, it is not. I installed GRUB and unpacked Ubuntu as said in the question. I edit the question to add details on partitions.